# Disable app nap for Ruby on Mavericks

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks

Is there a way to globally disable App Nap when running Ruby. I have a custom version installed via RVM which I can Get Info on in the Finder but the "Disable App Nap" option is not there. I don't know the domain name of Ruby to try the command line option: "defaults write ruby NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES". I tried ruby, org.ruby, org.ruby.ruby, and org.ruby-lang.ruby before giving up.

Comment: Seems like some Python people are having the same problems: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22861925-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-Python-Canopy

Comment: Sounds like QT 5.2 fixed a lot of Mavericks bugs so I might not solve this until I'm able to upgrade.

Comment: BTW You can issue "defaults domains" to find out all the application domains. I discovered mine was not what I expected. However disabling App Nap still did not help. I think QT 4.8.6 is the problem.

Comment: Another Mavericks QT App Nap conversation: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/37750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Nap is per app basis. You don't want to disable it for anything that uses Ruby.

An app is supposed to tell the system when the app is not allowed to nap (e.g, when you start a task), and when it is allowed back to nap (e.g, when the task ends). This would be done using NSProcessInfo class in Obj-C. Unfortunately that might mean finding a way to talk to Obj-C via a route such as Ruby -> C/C++ -> Obj-C, but such is the consequence of straying away from native libraries.

App Nap can be disabled entirely per app by setting the boolean user default key NSAppSleepDisabled to YES like you discovered. Via terminal, this could be done:

```
defaults write appbundleidentifier NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
```

This requires having set up an Info.plist in your app with your own bundle identifier.

Also, I believe if you link with the 10.8 SDK as opposed to the 10.9 SDK, you might get a "Prevent App Nap" checkbox when you Get Info on an application. The reasoning behind this is that if you link to 10.9 SDK, you are expected to implement App Nap for 10.9.

Comment: I think it's going to require a C extension to disable it. Might be a little more work but then it's solved across all my applications.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to disable; the Ruby interpreter (among most other command-line applications) is not subject to App Nap.

You may verify this from the "Energy" tab of Activity Monitor. You might need to make the "App Nap" column visible if it isn't already.

Comment: Some of my applications are Yes and some are No. I'm running QT GUI applications with Ruby and some spawn threads and others don't so I have a rather complex environment. It doesn't seem like I succeeded in disabling App Nap though and it is definitely negatively affecting me.